# linux crashes without syslog message

Tags: linux, crash, kernel, syslog

I have a server which is crashing.  The server runs a small number (3-5) of VMware machines.  It sometimes crashes when I start a new VM.  There are no messages in syslog or in the vmware log.  All I see on the console is the boot messages.

The system has 32Gb RAM.  Each of the VM's uses 2-4Gb.  I suspect memory problems, but a full run of memtest86 doesn't show any problems.

Any suggestions on how to capture the cause of the crash?

Comment: Use also `dmesg`, look into other files under `/var/log/` .... And try an intensive computation (like e.g. a kernel compile with `make -j 6`....) directly on the server (not thru a VM); several years ago I had RAM issues on a laptop without *memtest86* finding them ... (just borrowed some other RAM to find out); look also at temperature (with `yacpi`)

Answer (score 1):

You may use kernel module 'netconsole', to send kernel printk messages to remote syslog server.

Then you can check the log message in remote syslog server, event if the machine is crashed .

> ## Introduction:
>
> This module logs kernel printk messages over UDP allowing debugging of
>   problem where disk logging fails and serial consoles are impractical.
>
> It can be used either built-in or as a module. As a built-in,
>   netconsole initializes immediately after NIC cards and will bring up
>   the specified interface as soon as possible. While this doesn't allow
>   capture of early kernel panics, it does capture most of the boot
>   process. Check kernel document for more information:
>   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt